# Expression in GCC ARM assembly macro

Tags: gcc, assembly, macros, arm, neon

I'm in need of macros with many registers involved, like :

```
.macro load128bytes
  vld1.8 {d0, d1, d2, d3}, [r0]!
  vld1.8 {d4, d5, d6, d7}, [r0]!
  vld1.8 {d8, d9, d10, d11}, [r0]!
  vld1.8 {d12, d13, d14, d15}, [r0]!
.endm
```

As you can see, the registers are consecutive. However, I want to pass the number of starting register as an argument like :

```
.macro load128bytes srn
  vld1.8 {d\srn, d\srn+1, d\srn+2, d\srn+3}, [r0]!
  vld1.8 {d\srn+4, d\srn+5, d\srn+6, d\srn+7}, [r0]!
  vld1.8 {d\srn+8, d\srn+9, d\srn+10, d\srn+11}, [r0]!
  vld1.8 {d\srn+12, d\srn+13, d\srn+14, d\srn+15}, [r0]!
.endm
```

And of course, the above doesn't work. The assembler interprets them as : d0, d0+1, d0+2, d0+3 instead of d0, d1, d2, d3 what I intend them to be when srn is 0.

I searched the web and found an example that might solve this problem :

```
.macro  sum from=0, to=5
  .long   \from
  .if     \to-\from
    sum     "(\from+1)",\to
  .endif
.endm
```

Although the example above works fine, it didn't help solving my problems :

```
.macro  test    srn0
  vld1.8        {d"(\srn0)", d"(\srn0+1)"}, [r0]
.endm
```

Building above results in an error message : Neon double or quad precision register expected -- `vld1.8 {d"0",d"0+1"},[r0]'

Any ideas? It's really frustrating to pass up to sixteen registers each time, and even worse, it makes my code prone to errors.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum example works becuase it gives this output:

```
.long 0
.long (0+1)
.long ((0+1)+1)
.long (((0+1)+1)+1)
.long ((((0+1)+1)+1)+1)
.long (((((0+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)
```

Thus after macro expansion the assembler sees expressions where it expects expressions, and evaluates them. The trick you need is to get it to evaluate expressions where it *doesn't* expect expressions, and to do so *before* the assembly pass. To the rescue comes [alternate macro mode](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Altmacro.html#Altmacro) and CPP-style macro chaining (smaller example for clarity):

```
.macro _load32bytes base r0 r1 r2 r3
  vld1.8 {d\r0, d\r1, d\r2, d\r3}, [\base]!
.endm

.macro load32bytes srn
.altmacro
  _load32bytes r0, %(\srn), %(\srn+1), %(\srn+2), %(\srn+3)
.endm
```

The `%` operator allows evaluating an expression to a string arbitrarily during macro expansion - I couldn't seem to convince it to work within a single macro, but chaining does the job:

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-as -alm -mfpu=neon test.s
ARM GAS  test.s                         page 1


   1                    .macro _load32bytes base r0 r1 r2 r3
   2                      vld1.8 {d\r0, d\r1, d\r2, d\r3}, [\base]!
   3                    .endm
   4
   5                    .macro load32bytes srn
   6                    .altmacro
   7                      _load32bytes r0, %(\srn), %(\srn+1), %(\srn+2), %(\srn+3)
   8                    .endm
   9
  10                    load32bytes 0
  10                    > .altmacro
  10                    >  _load32bytes r0,%(0),%(0+1),%(0+2),%(0+3)
  10 0000 0D0220F4      >>  vld1.8 {d0,d1,d2,d3},[r0]!
  11                    load32bytes 3
  11                    > .altmacro
  11                    >  _load32bytes r0,%(3),%(3+1),%(3+2),%(3+3)
  11 0004 0D3220F4      >>  vld1.8 {d3,d4,d5,d6},[r0]!
  12
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you VERY much. BTW, I'm currently working on a big open source project consisting of pure hand crafted NEON assembly routines and an e-book on ARM optimizations. I'll let you know once they are finished. And of course, you'll receive a free "copy" of that e-book. :)